# Ionic Template Routing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i am trying to create an app with this way, i have ONE BLANK IONIC Template, and 2 sidebar based ionic templates.

In BLANK TEMPLATE i am using 2 icons. Which i click on 1st icon, it redirects the URL but not the page. And same with the second icon. Here i how my code looks like.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Another page i have is app.js. This is where all the routing comes:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('appa', {
    url: '/appa',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'homeoptions.html'

  })


    .state('appa.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'homeoptions.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('appa.fitness', {
    url: '/fitness',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'fitness-templates/fitness.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('appa.cafe', {
      url: '/cafe',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'cafe-templates/health.html',
          controller: 'TestCtrol'
        }
      }
    })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/appa/home');
});
```

I have my folder structure like this:

[image]

Why my page is not navigating ? I am just using the same procedure as its saying by the guide and from the examples.

Any idea will be helpful. Let us know your views.

Thank you! (In advance)

Comment: Without looking at your template setup, it's hard to tell my just looking at the router.

Comment: What file should i share? Should i share the index.html? or homeoptions.html?

Comment: Could you create a plunk? I've had to go through similar situation once.